# How to know if a TButton click executed a TAction?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I'm using TActions and TButtons in a VCL application. Setting the TButtons Action field to an existing action centralizes code.

An actions Execute method looks like this:

```
void __fastcall MyFrame::MyActionExecute(TObject *Sender)
{
//Some action code
}
```

Assigning the MyAction to a TButton named MyBtn and looking at the actions *ActionComponent*:

```
void __fastcall MyFrame::MyActionExecute(TObject *Sender)
{

  if(MyAction->ActionComponent == MyBtn)
  {
   //.. action code when the MyBtn was clicked..
  }
}
```

seem to work good.

However, calling the MyAction's Execute method *programatically*, like this:

```
MyActionExcecute(NULL);
```

seem to not set the ActionComponent to NULL, but 'still' uses the MyBtn as the ActionCompoent. So the if statement above does evaluate to true, even though the button was not clicked.

Question is, what is the proper way to handle both button clicks and manually calling an actions execute method?

I'm aware that I can check Sender parameter for NULL, and if so, I can assume that it was not the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action's [`ActionComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBasicAction.ActionComponent) property is set only when a UI control is firing the action, via an internal [`TBasicActionLink`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBasicActionLink) object that the control creates internally for itself. The link's [`Execute()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBasicActionLink.Execute) method has an `AComponent` parameter that the control passes its `Self`/`this` pointer to, to set the action's `ActionComponent` before calling the action's `Execute()` method.

For example, this is what the VCL does internally:

```pascal
procedure TControl.SetAction(Value: TBasicAction);
begin
  if Value = nil then
  begin
    ActionLink.Free;
    ActionLink := nil;
    ...
  end
  else
  begin
    ...
    if ActionLink = nil then
      ActionLink := GetActionLinkClass.Create(Self);
    ActionLink.Action := Value;
    ...
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
procedure TControl.Click;
begin
  { Call OnClick if assigned and not equal to associated action's OnExecute.
    If associated action's OnExecute assigned then call it, otherwise, call
    OnClick. }
  if Assigned(FOnClick) and (Action <> nil) and not DelegatesEqual(@FOnClick, @Action.OnExecute) then
    FOnClick(Self)
  else if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) and (ActionLink <> nil) then
    ActionLink.Execute(Self) // <-- HERE
  else if Assigned(FOnClick) then
    FOnClick(Self);
end;
```

```pascal
function TBasicActionLink.Execute(AComponent: TComponent): Boolean;
begin
  FAction.ActionComponent := AComponent; // <-- HERE
  Result := FAction.Execute;
end;
```

So, don't call your `OnExecute` event handler *directly*.  That will not update the action at all.  Call the action's [`Execute()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnList.TCustomAction.Execute) method instead.  You will just have to set the action's `ActionComponent` to NULL yourself beforehand, eg:

```cpp
MyAction->ActionComponent = NULL;
MyAction->Execute();
```

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBasicAction.ActionComponent) claims:

> When the user clicks a client control, that client sets `ActionComponent` before calling the action's `Execute` method. **After the action executes, the action resets `ActionComponent` to nil (Delphi) or NULL (C++)**.

However, the `ActionComponent` IS NOT reset automatically, only when the next time a UI control decides to execute the action for itself.

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. So the documentation saying that the ActionComponent is set to NULL after execution, is wrong and misleading?

Comment: @TotteKarlsson Yes. I double-checked with the VCL source code before posting my answer. Nothing resets the `ActionComponent` after the action is executed